# Load Javascript function from update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, viewstate

I have the following code -

```
 protected string Term
    {
        get { return this.ViewState["Term"] != null ? (string)this.ViewState["Term"] : ""; }
        set { this.ViewState["Term"] = value; }
    }
```

Then set `Term` -

```
public void populateTerm()
    {

        Term = "Test";    
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "term","useTerm()", true);

    }
```

Then in Javascript can use Term -

```
function useTerm() {
                    var Term = <%= Term %>;
                    // use Term
                 }
```

This works fine when the page is getting reloaded on the button click that was firing `populateTerm()`. However I have since moved the button into an `updatePanel`, so because the entire page is not getting reloaded on button click (only the update panel), this means that `useTerm()` is not called and `<%= Term %>` is null.

If I remove the updatePanel code it works fine. How can I get this to work with the updatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the function `useTerm` is in you aspx page, you can move that script block within the `UpdatePanel` `ContentTemplate`.

An alternative would be to change the JavaScript function so term is passed in as a parameter:

```
function useTerm(term) {
    // use term
}
```

and then to call it with the latest value of `Term`:

```
public void populateTerm()
{

    Term = "Test";    
    string script = string.Format("useTerm('{0}');", Term);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "term", script, true);

}
```